# Probability in a range

Tags: probability

Suppose $0 \leq z \leq 20 $

What is the probability that $10 \leq z \leq 15$?  $z$ is a real number.

Don't tell me the answer. It is my homework, but I missed my class so I don't know how to do it. Please guide me.

Comment: The question as it stands is meaningless.  Just telling me the range of values $z$ can take doesn't tell me the *distribution* of $z$.  For instance, $z$ could be $0$ with probability $1$.  Then we have $0\leq z\leq20$, and the probability that $10\leq z\leq15$ is $0$.  On the other hand, $z$ could be uniquely $10$ with probability $1$.  Then the probability that $10\leq z\leq15$ is $1$.  I imagine you mean that $z$ is uniformly distributed in the interval $[0,20]$.  Then the answer is -----------

Answer (score 1):

Think about it geometrically. You are picking a random point on the line:

```
+--------------------+
0                    20
```

and you want the probability that the point you pick is in a specific region on this line:

```
          10    15
          |     |
+---------=======----+
0                    20
```

Comment: So we're just assuming all variables are uniformly distributed now?

Comment: @ChrisEagle Yes, that was my assumption. I will change/delete this answer if the OP indicates that this is not the case.